# Using Facepy to request facebook data

Tags: django, facebook-graph-api, python-2.7

This is probably a silly question, but I been scratching my head over this for far too long.

I am trying to request the photo information from the facebook GraphAPI using Facepy/social-auth in django.

My view has the following code, but how do i turn the resulting json into python objects?

```
instance = UserSocialAuth.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(provider='facebook')
graph = GraphAPI(instance[0].extra_data['access_token'])
p=graph.get('me/photos')
```

Facepy seems very good, but the documentation is poor at best, is there a better python facebook sdk that plays nice with social-auth?

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Facepy returns native Python objects, not JSON.

```
response = graph.get('me/photos')

for photo in response['data']:
    print photo['source']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simplejson's loads function

```
from django.utils import simplejson
simplejson.loads(args)
```

> Deserialize `s` (a `str` or `unicode` instance containing a JSON
>       document) to a Python object.
>
> ```
> If ``s`` is a ``str`` instance and is encoded with an ASCII based encoding
> other than utf-8 (e.g. latin-1) then an appropriate ``encoding`` name
> must be specified. Encodings that are not ASCII based (such as UCS-2)
> are not allowed and should be decoded to ``unicode`` first.
>
> ``object_hook`` is an optional function that will be called with the
> result of any object literal decode (a ``dict``). The return value of
> ``object_hook`` will be used instead of the ``dict``. This feature
> can be used to implement custom decoders (e.g. JSON-RPC class hinting).
>
> ``parse_float``, if specified, will be called with the string
> of every JSON float to be decoded. By default this is equivalent to
> float(num_str). This can be used to use another datatype or parser
> for JSON floats (e.g. decimal.Decimal).
>
> ``parse_int``, if specified, will be called with the string
> of every JSON int to be decoded. By default this is equivalent to
> int(num_str). This can be used to use another datatype or parser
> for JSON integers (e.g. float).
>
> ``parse_constant``, if specified, will be called with one of the
> following strings: -Infinity, Infinity, NaN, null, true, false.
> This can be used to raise an exception if invalid JSON numbers
> are encountered.
>
> To use a custom ``JSONDecoder`` subclass, specify it with the ``cls``
> kwarg.
> ```